# Tomcat 7 web configuration

Tags: java, unix, tomcat7, business-objects

We have tomcat 7.0.55 in our Unix server. We have deployed web applications manually inside webapps folder of tomcat instance. By default the `clusterinfo.1200.properties` and log4j logs are stored in `.businessobjects` folder under home directory of the user account in which tomcat runs.

While accessing the InfoView web application we get the below error

> "AccessControlException:"java.io.filePermission:Access Denied \home<user account of tomcat>.businessobjects\clusterinfo.properties"

Tomcat 7 has restriction to access the file outside the tomcat directory on the first logon. However on refreshing the page we are able to access the application.

I have tried the following steps.

1. stopped the tomcat instance
2. Moved `.buisnessobjects` from home directory to inside tomcat installed directory.
3. Created symlink as `.businessobjects` in home directory to point to the folder inside tomcat directory.
4. Started the tomcat instance.

It works. But I need to know where the configuration change has to be made in web application to place the clusterinfo property file and log4j file inside tomcat directory.

I am a novice in Java. Please let me know the file and its location to make this changes.

Desperately looking for a solution :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to grant more permissions on this file with `chmod`. 
The exception explicitly says that its `java.io.filePermission`. So the problem is that jvm can't read your properties file because your OS prevents it from doing so based on the file permissions. 
You can see file permissions with `ls -l filepath`. 
I vaguely remember that you had to change owner of the accesed files in order for tomcat to work so `chown tomcat7 \home\<user account of tomcat>\.businessobjects\clusterinfo.properties` wouldn't hurt, but I don't remember if it was only applicable to deployed artifacts like *.war files or such.

Comment: I tried giving file permission mode chmod 777 to .business objects folder in the home directory. Tomcat is using the same owner as that of the accessed file (.business objects) in home directory. I could notice that the web application is not able to access any folder outside tomcat directory.

Comment: Giving file permission on a directory is not enough. You should explicitly `chmod` on required file (`clusterinfo.properties` in your case as I assume you didn't `chmod` the directory with `-R` option?).